# Selenium "sendkeys" does not work with a particular website but manually typing it in works

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

https://phytozome-next.jgi.doe.gov/blast-search

on this website if i use the blast tool with the sequence "MARPFTLSLLSLCLLLSAWSCFGGSSSTNRFNICQLNSLNALKPDHRVETDGGLVETWSSRHPELECAGVTVTRRTLYRNGFQMPSYSPYSQMIMAIQGKGALGLALSGCAETYEEPAKESSSSSQKPSDSHQKIRQFDQGHVMLIPRGVPFWIFNTGDEPLITVTLLDTSSEDNQLDQSPREFYLAGNPDIEHPEAMKEKQQQQAEEEGGNVLSGFGKRFLARALNIDQDTANKLISPDDEMKQIVKLKEGLSVISPKWQGQQEDEDEDDDDEDEDESVSRPSRRPSHGKRVHKEEETVVEPYPHGKHVHKEVEKEVEPLPPRKHVHKEEEKEIEPLPPRRSRHHHDEGEDEGEEEEKPRARRTRGPTPSPKGEGHRGVEEEDESEDTKGHKTRHEKTRHEKSWKEHRPEGEDVEKGEAHEEWETRPSKDKPHGSNGLDETICSSKLQFNIARPKGADFYNPKAGRIKNLNSQSLPALQHFGLSAQYVVLYKNGIYSPHWNMDANSVIYVIRGQGQVRVVNNEGIVMFDDELKKGQLLVVPQNFMVAEEAGDQGFEYVVFKTNDNAVTSYLKETFRAFPAEVLVNIYKLKHSQVHDLKYNGNLGPLVNPENSLDQSS"

along with Archaeplastida selected in order to return all results i get 100 results

when i use selenium with the chrome driver the web page informs me that "The Phytozome service couldn't get what you were after."

i have narrowed the problem down to something involving send keys, since if i run selenium all the way up to the point where it sends keys and i input the keys myself it works just fine.

Comment: can you post your code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure what the problem was but i simply used execute script instead of send keys. that posed another issue, which i resolved by sending a space key and then clicking backspace.

i tried everything including sending the keys one by one with a space in between and this was the only thing that worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you say you "input the keys yourself", are you really typing those hundreds of random-looking letters yourself, one at a time? That looks about impossible.

It totally depends on the particular website's programming, but it could be a timing issue. You can try a separate SendKeys() call for each character with a pause between each one.

Comment: i wouldn't say typing that is impossible. but i was copy pasting